# Do I have to buy ESO for Xbox One if I already own it for PC?

Tags: xbox-one, the-elder-scrolls-online

I own The Elder Scrolls Online for PC and want to switch to Xbox One.

Do I have to buy an Xbox One specific copy of the game or can I activate the game on Xbox One with my PC key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to buy it on every platform you want to play.